# How can I visualize specific data points in a boxplot in R?

Tags: r, boxplot

I have some monthly time-series data and I need to create a boxplot on this data using R. Until here, no problem of course. Then, additionally to the median, 1st quartile and 3rd quartile, I also need to visualize in the graph specific data points coming from the time-series, namely the observations at 3 years, 1 year and 3 months in the past. I looked online but I can't seem to find any command for this. Is there a way I can add these observation to the boxplot?

Comment: When you use `boxplot` you may use `points(..., add=TRUE)` to easily achieve an overlay of a boxplot with points!

Answer (score 1):

You can use, for example, the `text` function:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(100, 5, 10)
```

If you want to display the mean value:

```
boxplot(x)
text(1, mean(x), "x", col = "red")
```

Additionally or alternatively, you can use the function `points`:

```
points(IQR(x), col = "blue", pch = 8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just one last thing. I actually have many time series and I need to create a boxplot on the same page for each of them. So, I need to add points to different graphs. How can I make R understand that I need to add one point to one boxplot and then another point to another boxplot instead that still on the first one?